# Raspberry PI: VLC --play-and-exit not working

Tags: vlc, raspberry-pi4

VLC Version

> VLC media player 3.0.16 Vetinari (revision 1.0.6-1682-g88158c836)
> VLC version 3.0.16 Vetinari (1.0.6-1682-g88158c836)
> Compiled by pi on serge-testpi (Nov 10 2021 15:40:45)

This VLC came default with the latest PI Image since omxplayer no longer supported, and I need to upgrade my code to use VLC.

It refuses to quit after play my video

```
vlc --fullscreen --play-and-exit example.m4v vlc://quit
```

Comment: Better suited for https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Move to raspberry pi forum....